# Was the 501st an Elite Group before the Rise of the Empire?

Tags: star-wars

In honor of this being the 501st question tagged star-wars, I have related it to the 501st Legion:

After Operation: Knightfall and the transformation of Anakin Skywalker, the 501st Legion was placed under the command of Lord Vader and became known as "Vader's Fist", and were an elite stormtrooper contingent. During the Clone Wars, there were elite clone units (like ARC troopers and Clone commandos), but was the 501st an elite group at this time? They participated in a lot of notable missions with a high success rate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**T-canon sources (the Clone War animated series) paint them as an already existing group of elite clones serving with Jedi General Anakin Skywalker and [Clone Captain CT-7567](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/CT-7567), nicknamed "Rex."**

Because of Skywalker's less than orthodox leadership techniques and the operational latitude he gave the soldier's of the 501st, they were able to complete extraordinary missions under difficult circumstances, establishing themselves as a crack team.

> Among the 501st's earliest battles was the [Battle of Christophsis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Christophsis), where they served under Skywalker, Captain Rex, and High Jedi General Obi-Wan Kenobi. Based out of Crystal City, the 501st troops managed to recapture Christophsis from the Confederacy, beating back Separatist General Whorm Loathsom's multiple assaults. However, Loathsom soon deployed a deflector shield to protect his battle droid troops, and the clone troopers were forced to pull back and defend the Republic's heavy cannons. After Skywalker and his newly assigned Padawan, Ahsoka Tano, destroyed the shield generator, the heavy cannons annihilated the droids and forced the Separatists to surrender. [-- Wookieepedia > 501st Legion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/501st_Legion)

Comment: The Clone Wars TV series is canon (it is actually only subordinate to G-canon - which are the actual films, their scripts, and statements by Lucas). Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: I keep hearing how it isn't canon, sometimes from this very site. So when in doubt, I respond with the show as non-canon. But I love the series and have watched EVERY episode, more than once.

Comment: According to wikipedia, it is T-canon...but maybe I should ask a question about it

Comment: Based on the question I asked here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19209/is-star-wars-the-clone-wars-animated-tv-series-canon it is indeed canon