# Is Star Wars: The Clone Wars animated TV series canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_canon), it falls into T-canon. But following source notes lead to dead links. I have been told by some that it is not canon, and others say it is. Can anyone provide current sources that show it either is or is not canon?

Comment: This is touched on by [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars?rq=1) though it doesn't specifically answer for cartoons.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sadly yes the Cartoon is higher level canon than the novels:

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon

[From Lucas:](http://www.tgdaily.com/entertainment/63983-clone-wars-trailer-fears-the-sith)

> "This is Star Wars, and I don’t make a distinction between [Clone
>   Wars] and the films," Lucas said in an interview released by SciFiNow
>   - a science-fiction enthusiast magazine based in the UK - during last season.

Here is some [more reading on the canon](http://www.canonwars.com/SWCanon2.html).

UPDATE January 2014:  Disney will soon be revising the way canon works.  There will only be canon and non canon and the intent appears to be to wipe away most of the EU from canon. [SOURCE](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/star-wars-spinoffs-will-matter-668958)

Comment: That's what I thought! Thanks!

Comment: Good link too. Very thorough

Comment: The best part is that it's more canon than RotS novelization, which mentions that Skywalker and Kenobi haven't met Dooku since Geonosis... ;D

Comment: Any chance Disney will de-canon the prequels?!

Comment: @wikis - Probably not... but we can hope and send them emails begging them to.  Maybe we can get them to retcon it all into a Yoda dream sequence

Comment: I assume even with this new canon update a lot of the cartoon material will stay canon. The 2003 Clone Wars was especially made to tie into the movies, 2008 series probably quite a bit less.

Comment: @cen - not from what I read.  It sounds like they are wanting to wipe away the EU entirely so that they can do their own thing.

Comment: Yeah, except there is almost no actual canon for the events of clone wars so they'll have to use something from EU to fill these gaps. Basically, there is nothing to remove. :)

Comment: @cen - Right now the CW cartoon series is T Cannon.  That is just one step below the movies and a step above the novels.  By wiping away all of the EU (assuming that means T and below not just S and below) Disney will be able to rewrite any stories as it sees fit.  I expect Disney will thoroughly piss off the fanboys with what they do.

Answer (score -4):

The only star wars that Lucas calls canon are: The Clone Wars TV show, Force Unleashed 1(for 2, no info from Lucas), radio drama that are more extended Ep. 4-6 and the new live show that will come out. This is all that I can call G-canon (not bad for almost 40 years)

Comment: I think you sadly misunderstand the complexity of Star Wars canon - virtually EVERYTHING that bears the Star Wars label is canon, but there are varying levels of canon which determine which is correct if two sources differ.  [See this question for more info](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars?rq=1)

Answer (score -4):

*Star Wars: The Clone Wars* series IS NOT CANON. See star wars episode 3, the scene where they meet General Grievous for the FIRST time. During Episode 3 there is also a conversation between Obi-wan and Anakin about padawans that states "Never had a padawan, never will" This 2 factors not only prove the clone wars series canon in doubt, but also ANYTHING AND EVERYTHING created by Disney and other companies.

I'm not a die hard fan, but still, continuity errors piss me off to no end.
This extends to Star Trek the new series as well.

Comment: The question is asking about the official position of Lucasfilm/Disney toward the Clone Wars TV series. This isn't the correct forum to express your own personal opinions about the show.

Comment: There is no such conversation during *Revenge of the Sith*. In fact, there are only two mentions of the word "padawan" in the script. The first is Obi-Wan and Anakin discussing his belief that the council still treats him as a padawan. The second is Yoda and Obi-Wan discussing a padawan who had been killed.